pop up not showing up
Recently we moved our WPF Application on dot net 6, and we discovered that one of the one of the control is not working. It kind of a custom combo box control that work as a popup to a button, so whenever we click on the button a popup is shown, but after migration that pop up is not visible.
// this is the control that is supposed to popup on button click
public class BalonCtrl : ContentControl
{
  static BalonCtrl()
  {
    DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(BalonCtrl), 
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(BalonCtrl)));
  }

  // some properties like 

  public void Show()
  {
    var popup = new PopUp()
    {
      RenderTransform = new ScaleTransform(App.Window.ApplicationScale, App.Window.ApplicationScale),
      Focusable = true,
      MinWidth = MinWidth,
      PlacementTarget = Target as FrameworkElement,
      Child = this, // <== Delegate the Content to the Popup so that it can render it
      AllowsTransparency = true,
      StaysOpen = false,
      Placement = Placement,
      PlacementRectangle = PlacementRectangle,
      PopupAnimation = PopupAnimation.Slide
    };

     popup.isOpen = true;
  }

}


// This is how the above piece of code is being called
onButtonclick()
{
 
 var list = new windows.ComboBoxPopup();

 var balloon = new windows.BalonControl()
 {
   Content = list,
 };

ballon.show();


}




When I remove the Content, which a content propert in ContentControl class, from the balloon object and set listbox as child directly in BallononControl show method, the pop up works, just styling is the issue.
I'm mostly concerned with why this behavior is happening is there something I can do to fix it.

It doesn't look like it has anything to do with .NET 6. It rather looks like a refactoring error.
The point is that BalloonControl is a ContentControl. In order to make it show it must be a child of a visual tree (which BalloonControl isn't). The only chance to display any content is to delegate it to the Popup that BalloonControl creates and shows. But you never do this. Instead, you set the Popup.Child to the BalloonControl instance itself. Just fix the Popup initialization.
Important!
You are currently creating a potential memory leak for the BalloonControl. If you retain a reference to a BalloonControl instance and call Show again, the old Popup won't get garbage collected because the event handlers of BalloonControl are keeping it alive.
To be on the safe side for the future (when you forgot about those details or when other developers that don't know the implementation details use that code) you should a) use the WeakEventManager to listen to the Popup events or b) unregister all event handlers from the Popup.Closed event or c) reuse the Popup and only update the Popup.Child property (lifetime of Popup and BalloonControl is now the same).
The fixes applied to your example:
public class BalloonControl : ContentControl
{
  static BalloonControl()
  {
    DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(BalloonControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(BalloonControl)));
  }

  // some properties like 

  public void Show()
  {
    var popupContent = this.Content;
    this. Content = null;
    _Popup = new Popup()
    {
      RenderTransform = new ScaleTransform(App.Window.ApplicationScale, App.Window.ApplicationScale),
      Focusable = true,
      MinWidth = MinWidth,
      PlacementTarget = Target as FrameworkElement,
      Child = popupContent, // <== Delegate the Content to the Popup so that it can render it
      AllowsTransparency = true,
      StaysOpen = false,
      Placement = Placement,
      PlacementRectangle = PlacementRectangle,
      PopupAnimation = PopupAnimation.Slide
    };

    this.SizeChanged += OnSizeChanged;
    _Popup.Opened += OnPopupOpened;
    _Popup.Closed += OnPopupClosed;
    _Popup.IsOpen = true;
  }

  private void OnPopupOpened(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    Mouse.Capture(_Popup.Child, CaptureMode.SubTree);
    // right now up or down only
    if (PointerOrientation == Common.PointerOrientation.Bottom)
    {
      var target = Target as FrameworkElement;
      if (target != null)
      {
        Point pt = target.TranslatePoint(PlacementRectangle.TopLeft, Content as FrameworkElement);
        if (pt.Y > 0)
        {
          PointerOrientation = Common.PointerOrientation.Top;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  private void OnPopupClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    this.SizeChanged -= OnSizeChanged;
    _Popup.Opened -= OnPopupOpened;
    _Popup.Closed -= OnPopupClosed;

    if (IsCancelled)
    {
      if (OnCancel != null) OnCancel(this, new EventArgs());
    }
    else
    {
      if (OnApply != null) OnApply(this, new EventArgs());
    }
  }

  private void OnSizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e) 
  {
    if (Placement == PlacementMode.Top || Placement == PlacementMode.Bottom)
    {
      if (UseCanvasScale)
      {
        Graphic.GraphicCanvas canvas = Graphic.GraphicCanvas.FocusedCanvas;
        _Popup.HorizontalOffset = (-e.NewSize.Width / 2) / canvas.CanvasScale.ScaleX;
      }
      else
      {
        _Popup.HorizontalOffset = -e.NewSize.Width / 2;
      }
    }
  }
}


I did tried it too, But I'm having an Error as Specified element is a logical child to other element.  I know why this is happening, the only work around that I can think of was to create a separate property and assign that to child. The popup seems to work in that case. The only thing I don't understand and the reason I think it's a dot net 6 problem is that the same code was correctly working in previous version which was 4.8.

You must set the Content property to NULL. I will update the example.

Are you sure that it was the exact same code? It's impossible that this has ever worked. Impossible.

Yup!!!  exact same code, I re-verified and the code is exactly same. This is those part of the code that we didn't touch while refactoring.

Do my suggestions fix your issue? Regarding your broken source code. If this code was never touched then the issue is something else. Are you missing anything? Maybe you miss the default style of the BalloonControl that has to be defined in Generic.xaml? The Popup can only render the BalloonControl if the default style or a override style was found. This would explain why the Popup shows nothing. The code you have shown is so basic. I'm convinced that is not related to the change of the target framework. Please check that the default style is located in the correct Generic.xaml file.

Thanks for suggestion, Let me look at that and get back to you.

Sorry for being late, a bit update update on this:
The balloon control has a style hence that is not the issue. The Fix that you gave, I have already tried it, and its going to be the last measure if nothing works.
My Main concern is what changed between dotnet 4 and dotnet 6 that this issue is occurring. As explained in question the following code works fine in previous version, I debugged and compared and it is exactly same.

So the popup is able to render content of balloon control in previous version but not in dot net 6.
This balloon control is being used at other place where content is different and it is not working there also, though everything seems to work in correctly in previous versions.

Really difficult to tell without knowing more details. I'm pretty convinced that this has nothing to do with the target framework version (except you missed to provide essential details). The only reasonable explanation I have is that you missed the default style in Genric.xaml. You can try to reverse engineer the issue. Create a blank project which targets the framework currently in use and which you believe has broken your code. Then move the control to this project. and use it there. It's just a Popup. Nothing big. I would expect everything to work as usual.

Then add more code to replicate the usage in your current application (e.g. external resource or additional styles etc). At some point you should be able to break your control again. If you have managed to create a minimal reproducible example you can create a GitHub repo to allow me to review your control and relevant context. I'm pretty sure the issue is some small details which makes you laugh when realizing that is was in front of your eye all the time.

You were right, It was styling issue only, basically Balloon Control's style is not referenced correctly.

Nice. I'm glad I could help to sort things out.
